# python sqlalchemy, get only one column problem

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hello I want to get only one query column using only `Table.select()`, but I am having a problem

```py
guild_id= 807887608943738881
guild = meta_data.tables['guild_'+str(guild_id)] 

a= engine.execute(guild.select([guild.c.age]).where(guild.c.user_id== user_id)).fetchall()
print(a)
```

This code returns this

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression for WHERE/HAVING role expected, got [Column('age', INTEGER(display_width=11), table=<guild_807887608943738881>)].
```

What's wrong with the `age` column?

Comment: You are using legacy constructs that may be confusing a more current version of SQLAlchemy. Try `with engine.connect() as conn:` followed by `a = conn.execute(select(guild.c.age).where(guild.c.user_id == user_id)).all()`

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are applying an illegal comparison in your `where clause`, as per this note in the documentation [3rd party integration issue](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/thirdparty.html). My first suggestion would be to verify the type in the columns. But since they match (as per your comment), my next thought is to rearrange your query syntax – perhaps your query is attempting to apply a filter on an already instantiated query (which does not allow filtering on additional fields):

```py
# Build your query according to v2.0 selector
q = guild.select(guild.c.age).where(guild.c.user_id== user_id)

# Get your results
res = engine.execute(q).fetchall()
```

Comment: no, data types are fine

Comment: I updated my solution @Cergey2202 -- let me know if this solves it for you. If not, I have some other ideas.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help either.

Comment: Same error? @Cergey2202